# Clipping Demdata raster with polygon bounds using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip

I am using ArcMap.

I am having some problem clipping the demdata raster to my polygons att taking the max and min value of height within that polygon. I tried using the "Raster To Polygon" method and then clip but it doesn't work.

[image: The demdata i want to clip to the polygons]

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product?

Comment: regular ArcMap and also pyscripter to code

Comment: You are trying to clip off the DEM based on the Red Polygons? If yes try using extract by mask.

Comment: Extract Values to Table might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two pieces - clipping by the red polygons, and then extracting the max/min values.

To clip use [Extract by Mask](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) (demdata as input raster, red polygons as input mask). This will get you new small raster layers of only those areas under the red polygons. If you do not care about these raster subsets as their own layers then skip this step - it is not necessary for the next step.

To extract the max/min values you can use [Zonal Statistics as Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) (red polygons as input zones, demdata as input value raster). This tool will calculate the max, min, and a handful of other statistics (if desired) for the raster area within each polygon and output this information in a table that can be joined back to your polygon layer.

If your end goal is just to calculate max/min per polygon you DO NOT NEED to do the Extract by Mask step - just use Zonal Statistics as Table.